# Finding numbers in a given range MySQL SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

My DDL Schema for a table looks like this...

```
CREATE TABLE StockCodes (
    stockCode SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    stockName VARCHAR(100),
    stockStart SMALLINT,
    stockFinish SMALLINT,
    stockCurrentNumber SMALLINT
);
```

How do implement stockCurrentNumber, such that I get a list of records like... stockCurrentNumber 001, 002, 003, 004, 005.

Also, how do I bundle the stockCode and stockCurrentNumber to form a composite primary key.

Also, how would I remove an individual stockCurrentNumber when removing stock?

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: What is the difference between `StockCode` and `StockCurrentNumber`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff stockCode and stockCurrentNumber should be bundled together to form a primary composite key.

Comment: Can you show examples of the data in the table, what query you have attempted to run so far, and how the result of this query differ from what you want? Right now, it is not clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Define with `ZEROFILL` on the column.

```
stockCurrentNumber smallint(3) unsigned zerofill
```

This causes all the insertions into the column be leading `0` padded.

**Example**:
When you insert `1`, it will be stored as `001`. You can compare with actual values like `field = 1`.

And when the same is used to concatenated with other values, padded zeroes are not lost.

**Example**:
If `stockCode` is `6` and `stockCurrentNumber` is `9` then

```
concat( stockCode, stockCurrentNumber )
```

will result `6009`.

**Refer to**:
[***MySQL: SMALLINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html#idm47447272126416)

Comment: ZEROFILL may the answer, but it's not at all accurate to say that the value is padded with zeros when it's stored. The ZEROFILL attribute doesn't have any influence on what's stored; it only influences the values that are retrieved.

Comment: That said, when called `length( zero_fill_field )` or `char_length( zero_fill_field )` what should it be returning?

Comment: The `LENGTH()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()` functions return the length of the string (argument), in bytes and characters, respectively. MySQL will retrieve the value from the `zero_fill_field` column, convert it to string, then the `LENGTH()` function will return the number of bytes in the string. A `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` will use bytes of storage, entirely independent of the value stored and the `ZEROFILL` attribute (apart from the normal row overhead for the NULL indicator, etc.)

Comment: I could not find any documentation on how a `zerofill` data is *stored* but *retrieved*. Can you share if you have one?

Comment: A column defined as `TINYINT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` still only uses one byte of storage for each row, but returns a string of length 10.  References: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) and [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: There's not really a reference about how a columm with the ZEROFILL attribute is *stored* because it's *stored* the same as any other column of the same type, independent of the length modifier or the ZEROFILL attribute.

Comment: @Ravinder you legend! Can't thank you enough. By the way where should I use concat(stockCode, stockCurrentNumber)? Also, how do I get all the numbers from the range between stockStart and stockFinish, and then insert them into stockCurrentNumber

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you well:

This is how you create a table with a composite primary key, notice `stockCurrentNumber` is varchar not to lose the left `0`

```
CREATE TABLE StockCodes (
stockCode SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
stockName VARCHAR(100),
stockStart SMALLINT,
stockFinish SMALLINT,
stockCurrentNumber varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(stockCode, stockCurrentNumber)
);
```

Then to delete:

```
DELETE FROM StockCodes WHERE stockCode='x' AND stockCurrentNumber='y';
```

Comment: yes, say for example stockStart = 1 & stockFinish = 10, how do I get a table with stockCurrentNumber like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10